# Balls into bins : minimum bins for that the chance of having an empty bin at the end is larger than 50%?

Tags: probability, balls-in-bins

We throw *X* times *N* balls into *K* bins. Each time, we remove bins that are not empty. What is the minimum amount of bins such that the chance of having an empty bin at the end is larger than 50% ?

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Do you want the minimum number of bins needed to ensure that there is at least 1 bin empty in the end? In that case the answer is $XN+1$. I'm not sure what you mean with the average amount of bins.

Comment: That's what I need, yes. But if I perform manually the experiment a lot of times with X = 6 and N = 17 for example, I find that with 78 bins, we have on the average of all results  an empty bin at the end.

Comment: That is actually a different question, I believe you could frame it as: What is the minimum amount of bins such that the chance of having an empty bin at the end is larger than 50%. Is this what you want to know?

Comment: Absolutely.Thanks for the clarification. I edit the question.

Comment: You remove bins that have balls and you keep those bins that doesn't have any balls then won't you end up with a empty bin with 100% probablity

Comment: No, suppose that you have 2 urns and two balls, 50% of the time you'll have an urn leftover and 50% of the time you will have no urns leftover.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can model this as a Markov chain.  For a given number of balls, each state will consist of the number of throws left and the number of bins left.  You can calculate the transition probabilities.  It is easiest to start with the last throw.  As an example, we take the case of $4$ balls.  If on the last throw there is only one bin, the chance of having none at the end is $1$.  If on the last throw there are two bins, the chance of having none at the end is $\frac 78$ because to have on left the last three balls thrown have to match the first one.  If on the last throw there are three bins, the chance of having none at the end is $\frac {3\cdot {4 \choose 2}\cdot 2}{3^4}=\frac {36}{81}$ because we have to distribute the balls $2-1-1$ and we choose the bin to get two, which two balls it gets, and the empty bin the first other ball goes in.  If on the last throw there are four bins, the chance of having none at the end is $\frac {4!}{4^4}=\frac {24}{256}$

If we have two throws at four bins, we can compute the chance of having none after the first throw is $\frac {24}{256}$.  The chance of having one is $\frac{ 4\cdot 36}{4^4}=\frac {144}{256}$ because we can choose three bins in four ways, then use the previous computation.  The chance of having three is $\frac 4{256}$ because all the balls have to go in the same bin.  The chance of having two is then $\frac {104}{256}$